# Syntax highlight fail for Prolog files

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype

I'm having trouble configuring Vim on Manjaro:

After setting `syntax on` at `.vimrc` file, I make a Prolog program (`bug.pl`) which shows no syntax highlight:

[image]

But after I append `/**/` to top of file (then quit and restart vim), highlighting somehow works:

(`/**/` is comment in Prolog, same like that of C)

[image]

So how do I have highlight without that useless `/**/`?

> DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
>
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.0.1
>
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=Gellivara
>
> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Mar  6 2017 14:13:23)

Update:

Suggested by grodzik, it's about filetype conflict.

I fix it by adding `au FileType perl set filetype=prolog` to my `.vimrc`. (Make sure it's **AFTER** `syntax on`)

Now I see highlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because by default a file with extension `.pl` is for Perl files.
If you open your file, when there is no `/**/` on first line and run command `:set filetype?`, it will show `perl`, not `prolog`.

However, if you add `/**/` on the first line, than there is probably some code inside Vim's standard distribution, that detects that and sets file type as `prolog` - again, check it with `:set filetype?`

If you know that you won't need `perl` syntax highlighting, than you can add to `.vimrc`:

```
au FileType perl set filetype=prolog
```

but rember, that this will disable `perl` file type for good. I think that better way is to prepend a file with that `/**/`, and let Vim detect the correct file type.

Comment: I do add `au FileType perl set filetype=prolog` to my `.vimrc`, and `set filetype?` return `filetype=prolog`. Still I see plain text without highlight. How do I do?

Comment: Do you still have `syntax on` in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: I copy `syntax on` to the line before `au FileType ...` then it works

Answer (score 3):

[grodzik has already explained why this occurs](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12378/343), but I disagree with his suggested solution. As he explains, using his autocommand means that it will be impossible *ever* to use the `perl` file type. Even if you believe you will never want to view a Perl file, this still seems unnecessarily final.

A gentler solution is to just set the filetype directly for files with `.pl` extensions. You can then still set the `perl` filetype manually with the command `:set filetype=perl` if necessary.

The Vim documentation describes how to do this in `:help new-filetype`, section C. In short:

Create a file `~/.vim/filetype.vim` with the contents:

```
" my filetype file
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.pl setfiletype prolog
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

I also just have been editing prolog file and discovered that there is something with default syntax highlighting. So I checked out he `:h filetype` and found the next:

[image]

So I added `% vim: set filetype=prolog :` to my prolog file and everything works now!

[image]

Sorry, I am a little late with the answer, but anyways... :)

Comment: The `/* */` aren’t needed. That’s probably an example C or Java modeline. `:help modeline`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks! All fixed now.

Comment: @VladyslavRehan What font are you using? That looks interesting.

Comment: @Rahn Glad You asked. I am using [Fantasque Sans Mono (normal)](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans/releases) font.

Comment: @VladyslavRehan Thanks! Using it now!